# Busybox udhcpd vfork starts two processes

Tags: c, linux, exec, busybox, vfork

In my application I require to start Busybox udhcpd (dhcp server), the code is below. While udhcpd does start and run I get two versions in the process list. udhcpd is running correctly, i.e. assigned IP addresses to devices.

```
pid_t forked_pid = vfork();

if ( forked_pid == 0 )
{
  // Child process, execute udhcpd.
  execl( "/usr/bin/udhcpd",
         "udhcpd",
         "/var/run/udhcpd.conf",   // the location of the udhcpd config file
         NULL );
}
else if ( forked_pid > 0 )
{
  // Parent process, record the childs pid
  m_udhcpd_pid = forked_pid;
  log( Log_Info, "UDHCPD started with PID: %d (PID=%d)", forked_pid, getpid());
}
else
{
  log( Log_Warning, "Failed to start UDHCPD" );
}
```

Log Output

UDHCPD started with PID: 647 (PID=528)

PS output

```
528 root       0:03 ./MyApp

647 root       0:00 [udhcpd]

648 root       0:00 udhcpd /var/run/udhcpd.conf
```

Now if I look at /var/run/udhcpd.pid it has the pid of 648. In another part of our code we start dhcpcd (dhcp client) using the same code as above and it only has one entry in the process list. Can anyone explain what the difference is and if I am doing things incorrectly what I should be doing?

The reason for asking is I require to later stop udhcpd and it seems I will need to stop using both the childs pid (647) and also the pid read from /var/run/udhcpd.pid (648).

Comment: Layers of the service.  Once the daemon is started (your pid 647), the system shows an instance, then depending on how system is configured, additional processes are started as needed.  Starting a similar instance in another part of your code may result in one more process, but does not require another instance of the daemon, for example.  Your `./MyApp` is already running, no need for another process ID, even though you used it to start another instance of `udhcpd` (pid 648)

Comment: It appears unrelated to your problem, but one really ought to use `fork()` rather than `vfork()` on any Linux system.  Quoth the Linux manual page for `vfork()`: "It is rather unfortunate that Linux revived this specter from the past."

Comment: Ryker, when I wrote "In another part of our code we start dhcpd..." above I  meant "dhcpcd" (and not udhcpd). I am only starting udhcpd once as shown above.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the answer is udhcpd does another fork leaving a zombie process. Reverted to just doing a system call and killing the process using the PID in the PID file.